# Attributed text with round corners

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want some range of text to be highlighted with rounded corner background.
I am able to set the background color of the required text range. But I am unable to make the background round cornered.
This is what I have so far:

[image]

Both the blue backgrounds text need to be round cornered. I found some solutions that achieve this using UILabel. But if I go for the UILabel solution, I'll have to make a major change in the project. Probably days of work.

Is there ANY possible way of achieving this through attributedText instead of UILabel or anything else?

Comment: So you just used NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor?

Comment: @Ryan yes. that's what I have done.

Comment: The previous answer is really the answer.